# Union with Redshift native tables and external tables (Spectrum)

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

If I have a view that contains a union between a native table and external table like so (pseudocode):

```
create view vwPageViews as 
   select from PageViews
   union all
   select from PageViewsHistory
```

PageViews has for the last 2 years. External table has for older data than 2 years.

- If a user selects from the view with filters for the last 6 months, how does RS Spectrum handle it - does it read the entire external table even though none will be returned (and accordingly cost us money for all of it)? (Assuming the s3 files are parquet based).

ex.

```
Select from vwPageViews where MyDate >= '01/01/2021'
```

What's the best approach for querying both cold and historical data using RS and Spectrum? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How this will happen on Spectrum will depend on whether or not you have provided partitions for the data in S3.  Without partitions (and a where clause on the partition) the Spectrum engines in S3 will have to read every file to determine if the needed data is in any of them.  The cost of this will depend on the number and size of the files AND what format they are in.  (CSV is more expensive than Parquet for example.)

The way around this is to partition the data in S3 and to have a WHERE clause on the partition value.  This will exclude files from needing to be read when they don't match on the partition value.

The rub is in providing the WHERE clause for the partition as this will likely be less granular than the date or timestamp you using in your base data.  For example if you partition on YearMonth (YYYYMM) and want to have a day level WHERE clause you will need to 2 parts to the WHERE clause - WHERE date_col >= 2015-07-12 AND part_col >= 201507.  How to produce both WHERE conditions will depend on your solution around Redshift.

Comment: Thanks! That's great to read about partition pruning. 
`If data is partitioned by one or more filtered columns, Amazon Redshift Spectrum can take advantage of partition pruning and skip scanning unneeded partitions and files`
[link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/10-best-practices-for-amazon-redshift-spectrum/#:~:text=Partition%20files%20on%20frequently%20filtered%20columns)

Comment: Yep, confirmed it with this query, from the link above. 
`SELECT query,
segment,
max(total_partitions) as total_partitions,
max(qualified_partitions) as qualified_partitions 
FROM svl_s3partition 
WHERE query=<Query-ID>
GROUP BY 1,2;`